# Create SQL Server login for site, but has no SQL Server access to browse

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, user-permissions

I have a contractor who I want to give access to a website that connects to a database. I need to create a SQL Server user that can connect and read and write to the database.

However, I don't want this user to be able to connect to the SQL Server via something like Management Studio. Are there permissions that need to be enabled or disabled to accomplish this in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is basically a normal client that makes SQL statements in the background. If you create a login in the SSMS, then no magic happens, but a CREATE LOGIN. This can be recognized by the fact that there is (almost) always the possibility to generate the appropriate SQL statement via "Script as", which is normally done in SSMS via the graphical user interface. 
If you would lock out SSMS, then other clients as well. And even if there were a setting, there are other possibilities via Powershell and the like. So this is not the way to go.

I suppose you don't want the contractor playing around on the SQL server just because he got access to a database? He is allowed in the house, but not in all rooms....

In other words, it can only be done via permissions, where there is a login to connect to the SQL Server on the one hand and a database user who gets access to the database on the other hand. Therefore there are authorizations on SQL server level (login) and database level (user).

```
CREATE LOGIN testlogin WITH PASSWORD = 'wowThisIsKewl';  
GO

USE [YourDatabase]
GO
CREATE USER [dbuserlogin] FOR LOGIN [testlogin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[db_owner]
GO
```

Each login belongs first to the [SQL Server role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017) "public", unless additional or different authorizations are granted. You can connect to this role, but e.g. you can not create databases, perform backups etc.... Just try it out.... =)

At the same time DB_OWNER at [database level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017) allows the login to read and write data, etc. and more.